# Remove starting 4 letters and ending 4 letters from a file name

Tags: linux, bash, shell, command

I would like to have a command that could strip the starting 4 letters and ending 4 letters from a filename. For ex: if the file name is:
form1234.tgz
I would like to get the number 1234 from the file name. Can someone suggest, a simple way this could be done on Linux on the command prompt?

Comment: Did you try finding similar questions of this nature and make an effort on your own?

Comment: I have used cut filter but want a better way of doing this.

Comment: Try this: echo $FILENAME | cut -b 5-$(expr ${#FILENAME} - 4)

Answer (score 1):

Removing the first four characters is easy using `cut`. Unfortunately, it doesn't have a built in way to remove characters from the end of a string, but you could always reverse it using `rev` apply `cut` and then `rev` it back again.

```
$ echo $FILENAME | cut -c5- | rev | cut -c5- | rev
```

Answer (score 0):

Use parameter substitution.

```
filename=form1234.tgz
short=${filename#????}
short=${short%????}
```

`#` removes from the left, `%` removes from the right.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a lot of options actually...

For this kind of things it would be better to match what you want instead of removing what you don't need: a typo could happen, or an already truncated file may be there...

For example, if you want to get rid of the extension, you can use [parameter expansion](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe), already supported in virtually every shell:

```
printf "%s" "${file%.*}"
```

If you need only numbers you can use a [regular expression](https://www.regular-expressions.info/):

```
printf "%s" "${file}" | sed -e "s/.*\([0-9]*\)\..*/\1/"
```

Let's say that your question is way generic and does not provide a lot of information of what you want...

If you want to statically remove the first and last 4 chars, you can use parameter expansions, `sed`, `cut`, `awk` or whatever you want...

For example with sed, it would be something like:

```
printf "%s" "${file}" | sed -e "s/^....\(.*\)....$/\1/"
```

With paramete expansion would be:

```
file="${file#????}"
file="${file%????}"
printf "%s" "${file}"
```

And finally, if you are in a pure bash environment, you can simply use some of bash parameter expansion (Note that this option will not work everywhere):

```
printf "%s" "${file:4:-4}"
```

Note that every `printf` could (obviusly) be replaced by `echo` (or `echo -n`).

Answer (score 0):

Probably the easiest if you know how many chars to strip off the beginning
and the end.

```
name=form1234.tgz

echo "${name:4:$((${#name} - 8))}"

1234
```